# How to create event listener that inject the view data in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I want to create event listener that add some results of db query to all symfony actions

for example:

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/blog/")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        ....

        return array(
            'entries' => $posts
        );
    }
}
```

This controller is passing `entries` variable to the view, I want to create listener that take the returned value of all actions and inject another index to the returned array to be (for example)

```
array(
    'entries' => $posts,
    'categories' => $categories
);
```

so I can call the `$categories` var from any where in my application views

I hope my question is clear to you guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want categories to be available in your twig templates?

Comment: @Cerad Yes, that what I want.

Comment: I think that the answer to this question is in this other thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549806/inject-twig-variable-symfony2.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider creating a [global variable](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html#referencing-services) or [twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) to make categories available in your templates, you can't do that by using events (since the template is parsed *inside* the controller, not before/after it)

Comment: It's not true the template is parsed inside the controller. It's parsed on kernel.view event AFTER the controller has been called. It's techinically possible to achieve what @Khalled Attia needs with events, regardless of wether that's the right solution or not.

Comment: @JakubZalas yeah, ok in this case it's parsed in the kernel.view event, but normally it would be parsed in the controller. :)

Answer (score 1):

This approach, although valid and commonly used in some frameworks, is not very common in Symfony as it suits more MVC than HMVC architecture.

I would suggest you a different one with the same result:

Instead of adding parameter to every controller return, render another controller which returns just a subview of what you're trying to show. Simple example:

```
 // article/index.html.twig

 <div class="category-bar">{{ render(controller('MyVendorMyBundle:CategoryController:bar')) }}</div>

 <div class="article-list">
     {% for article in articles %>
         {# Print article here #}
     {% endfor %}
 </div>

// CategoryController

class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Template
     */
    public function barAction()
    {
        return ['categories' => $this->fetchCategoriesSomehow()];
    }
}
```

So when you render your article list action, twig will fire a subrequest to render categories bar above it.

Furthermore, if you don't like making subrequests, nothing stops you from creating a twig extension service which would fetch categories and render template for you.

Answer (score 1):

**In most cases I would go with @Wouter J's suggestion and create a twig extension or a global variable.**

However, what you want to do is actually possible (regardless if that's the right solution or not).

The [@Template annotation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html) has a vars attribute, which lets you to specify which atttributes from the request should be passed to the template:

```php
/**
 * @ParamConverter("post", class="SensioBlogBundle:Post")
 * @Template("SensioBlogBundle:Post:show.html.twig", vars={"post"})
 */
public function showAction()
{
}
```

Note, that request attributes can be set by you:

```php
$request->attributes->set('categories', []);
```

So, you could implement a listener which would set the categories attribute on the request and than configure the `vars` on the `@Template` annotation:

```php
/**
 * @Template("SensioBlogBundle:Post:show.html.twig", vars={"categories"})
 */
public function showAction(Post $post)
{
}
```

Have a look at the [TemplateListener](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/TemplateListener.php) from the SensioFrameworkExtraBundle for more insight. The listener [defines template vars](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/TemplateListener.php#L50) on `kernel.controller` and [uses them to render the view](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/blob/master/EventListener/TemplateListener.php#L90) on `kernel.view`.

You could avoid defining `vars` on the annotation if your listener was registered after the `TemplateListener::onController()`. It would have to add categories to the `_template_vars` request attribute.

Comment: Having to add stuff to each controller is what the poster is trying to avoid.

Comment: And I explained how to avoid it in three ways: twig extension, global (also twig extension) and custom view/controller listener. Have you read full answer? ;)

Comment: Another possibility would be to register a listener *before* the TemplateListener on the `kernel.view` event and then append the categories variable to the controller result using `GetResponseForControllerResultEvent#setControllerResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Twig extension to create function that will return list of available categories

```
<?php

class CategoriesExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('getCategories', [$this, 'getCategoriesList'])
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getCategoriesList()
    {
        return CategoryQuery::create()->find();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the extension.
     *
     * @return string The extension name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'list_categories';
    }

}
```

You can pass parameter to function if You would like do some conditions on query.

Answer (score -1):

The trick is to get the twig service in your listener and then use addGlobal to add your categories

```
namespace Cerad\Bundle\CoreBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class MyEventListener extends ContainerAware implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => array(
            array('doCategories', -1100),
    );
}
public function doCategories(FilterControllerEvent $eventx)
{
    // Query your categories
    $categories = array('cat1','cat2');

    // Make them available to all twig templates
    $twig = $this->container->get('twig');
    $twig->addGlobal('categories',$categories);
}

# services.yml
cerad_core__my__event_listener:
    class:  '%cerad_core__my__event_listener__class%'
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: It'd be better to create a twig extension rather than a listener. Twig extension has getGlobals() method, which could return categories.

Comment: Nope.  You got it backwards.  Goal is to inject categories into the twig service.  After which, it becomes available to all templates without any additional effort.

Comment: You don't need a listener to do that. Twig extension is sufficient as it can provide globals. It is more appropriate since globals are twig related. You did what a twig extension would do but in a wrong layer.

Comment: Nope.  Business data should be pushed into twig, not pulled.